# axiosInstance.get can't display data

Tags: reactjs, http, axios

I want to display response of `axiosInstance.get`. I got response but it is not displayed. Can you help me to find a solution?

```
export default function Tour() {
    const { slug } = useParams();
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [data, setData] = useState({ tours: [] });

    useEffect(() => {
        axiosInstance.get('tours/?slug='+slug).then((res) => {
            const singleTour = res.data
            setData({ tours: singleTour });
            console.log(res.data);
        });
    }, [setData]);

    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="md">
            <CssBaseline />
            <div className={classes.paper}></div>
            <div className={classes.heroContent}>
                <Container maxWidth="sm">
                    <Typography
                        component="h1"
                        variant="h2"
                        align="center"
                        color="textPrimary"
                        gutterBottom
                    >
                        {data.tours.title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography
                        variant="h5"
                        align="center"
                        color="textSecondary"
                        paragraph
                    >
                        {data.tours.description}
                    </Typography>
                </Container>
            </div>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

There are no errors in network, but nothing is displayed in frontend

output of console.log(res.data)

```
0:
author: 1
description: "yoga yoga yoga yoga yoga"
end_date: "2022-01-15T14:25:31Z"
id: 1
reg_end_date: "2022-01-15T14:25:36Z"
reg_start_date: "2022-01-15T14:25:33Z"
slug: "tour"
start_date: "2022-01-15T14:25:30Z"
status: 2
title: "new yoga tour"
```

Comment: can you add the output of `console.log(res.data);` to the question?

Comment: Initial `data` state is that `tours` is an array, but you access in render as though it's an object. What are you updating the state to, i.e. what is the value of `res.data`?

Comment: `res.data` looks like it's an array. Are there ever more elements to render or will the response always be an array of length 1?

Comment: @DrewReese the response always will be an array of length 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the response is always an array of length one then I wouldn't bother storing it in state as an array. Store it as an object, which matches how it's accessed in the render and maintains a state invariant.

```
export default function Tour() {
  ...

  const [data, setData] = useState({ tours: {} }); // <-- use object

  useEffect(() => {
    axiosInstance.get('tours/?slug='+slug).then((res) => {
      const [singleTour] = res.data; // <-- array destructuring assignment
      setData({ tours: singleTour });
      console.log(res.data);
    });
  }, [setData]);

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="md">
      ...
        <Container maxWidth="sm">
          <Typography ... >
            {data.tours.title}
          </Typography>
          <Typography ... >
            {data.tours.description}
          </Typography>
        </Container>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}
```